# Expanding the Hamiltonian Matrix for Unit cell to that for Supercell

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter

Can I ask a question about the Hamiltonian expansion.

Suppose there is a two dimensional unit cell, containing 3 atoms without spin orbit coupling effect. Therefore, the Hamiltonian matrix for this unit cell is a $3\times3$ matrix and the format of each element in this unit-cell Hamiltonian is $t\times e^{ikd_{ij}}$. $t$, $k$ and $d$ are hopping parameter between different atoms, $k$ point coordinate and the bonding vector between different atoms $i$ and $j$ respectively. For instance, the Hamiltonian matrix is written below.

$$\begin{matrix}atom1 & atom2 & atom3\end{matrix}\\
\begin{vmatrix}
\epsilon_1 & t\times e^{ikd_{12}} & t\times e^{ikd_{13}}\\
t\times e^{-ikd_{21}} & \epsilon_2 & t\times e^{ikd_{23}}\\
t\times e^{-ikd_{31}} & t\times e^{-ikd_{32}} & \epsilon_3
\end{vmatrix}$$

Now, this unit cell is expanded to a $5\times5$ supercell. Would anyone please tell me how to expand the Hamiltonian matrix for this unit cell to that for the $5\times5$ supercell?

My own understanding is that I just need to copy the Hamiltonian for this unit and repeat it by 25 times. Every time I copy the Hamiltonian of unit cell, I just need to past it onto the diagonal part and leave the off-diagonal part zero. Finally, the Hamiltonian for this $5\times5$ supercell is just a $75\times75$ sparse matrix ($3\times5\times5=75$). The format of this supercell Hamiltonian is written below.

\begin{equation}
\begin{matrix}unitcell1 & unitcell2 & . & . & . & unitcell25\end{matrix}\\ \begin{vmatrix} H_{1}\\
&H_{2}&&\mbox{0}\\
&&H_{3}\\
&\mbox{0}&&\dots\\
&&&&H_{25}
\end{vmatrix}
\end{equation}

I am not sure whether my understanding is correct or not. Is it just simple copy-and-paste of the Hamiltonian matrix the for unit cell by 25 times?

Would anyone please give me some suggestions or hints on this issue?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I do not get your question. Could you please be much more specific what you consider. What is the system and the key effect you are interested in? Even a single atom has many energy levels. Therefore, it can be described by a Hamiltonian with many dimensions.

Comment: @Semoi Thank you for your reply. I modified my question. Would you please give me some suggestions on this Hamiltonian expansion? Thank you very much again.

Comment: @Semoi I have already modified my question with more details. Would you please vote to re-open my question? I really need help on this question, which has puzzled me for long time. Thank you very much.